# All elements within first list are sortable but only certain elements should be exchangeable with the second list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm loading 2 lists dynamically and I want to be able to have all the elements in the first list to be completely sortable but only certain elements with a specific class can be exchangeable with the second list.

I tried to restrain the elements with the class unsortable to go to the second list but this doesn't seem to work since the elements that have that class are not allowed to move within the first list. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    $(function () {

        $('#visibleElements').sortable({
            connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
            opacity: 0.8,
            placeholder: 'customPlaceholder',
            forcePlaceholderSize:true,
            start: function(e, ui){
                ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
            },
            receive: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item.hasClass("subject")) {
                    ui.item.removeClass('red');
                    ui.item.find("span.square").removeClass('redSquare');
                    ui.item.addClass('blue');
                    ui.item.find("span.square").addClass('darkBlueSquare');
                }
            },
            stop: function(ev, ui) {
                if (ui.item.hasClass("unsortable")) {
                    $(this).sortable("cancel");
                }
            }
        });

        $('#inactiveElements').sortable({
            connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
            opacity: 0.8,
            placeholder: 'customPlaceholder',
            forcePlaceholderSize:true,
            start: function (e, ui) {
                ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
            },
            receive: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item.hasClass("subject")) {
                    ui.item.removeClass('blue');
                    ui.item.find("span.square").removeClass('darkBlueSquare');
                    ui.item.addClass('red');
                    ui.item.find("span.square").addClass('redSquare');
                }
            },
        }).disableSelection();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to work it out by removing the **Stop** event from the first list and including the function inside the **Receive** event on the second list:

```
$(function () {

        $('#inactiveElements').sortable({
            connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
            opacity: 0.8,
            placeholder: 'customPlaceholder',
            forcePlaceholderSize:true,
            start: function (e, ui) {
                ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
            },
            receive: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item.hasClass("subject")) {
                    ui.item.removeClass('blue');
                    ui.item.find("span.square").removeClass('darkBlueSquare');
                    ui.item.addClass('red');
                    ui.item.find("span.square").addClass('redSquare');
                }
                if (!ui.item.hasClass("subject")) {
                    ui.sender.sortable("cancel");
                }
            },
        }).disableSelection();
    });
```